# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore sync delay when changing iCloud accounts

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, icloud, cloudkit

There's an issue I have been experiencing when switching test iCloud accounts in my device to test whether my app handles the iCloud account change detection correctly.

So I have data stored in both on CloudKit and `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`.

When I log out of iCloud account A using the iOS settings, the app gets automatically killed (which is OK I suppose). Then, when I log in with iCloud account B and relaunch the app, I get the correct iCloud account (B) when calling the `fetchUserRecordID` method.

The problem is though that the `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` doesn't get updated right away and the stored `.plist` file under `SynchedPreferences`, that the `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` maintains, still has the previous iCloud information even though I explicitly call the `synchronize` method after detecting the iCloud change.

The question here is, do I have to do something else to get the `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` sync to kick in when iCloud account changes? Or do I just have to wait for the `didChangeExternallyNotification` notification to occur, which may take from 3-30 minutes, or (in some other cases as I have noticed) might just require an app restart to kick in?

Answer (score 0):

You could try observing the `CKAccountChanged` object and see if that helps:

```
//AppDelegate.swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

  //Listen for iCloud account status changes
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(checkCloudKitStatus), name: Notification.Name.CKAccountChanged, object: nil)

  return true
}

@objc func checkCloudKitStatus(){
  //Do whatever you need to in order to switch iCloud accounts
}
```

Inside the `checkCloudKitStatus()` method, you could try gracefully handling the changes so that your app doesn't crash. I suspect the crash may be a sign that your app isn't properly handling the account change. You could also try refreshing `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` inside that method.

Comment: Hey Clifton! Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I have already tried listening to that notification to no avail: Although the notification is posted when the iCloud account  changes, and I explicitly call `synchronize()` to refresh the `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`, the KVS doesn't get updated along with the CloudKit account :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe Apple has set up a separate notification system called `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification` for logging into and out of iCloud as well as turning on/off your app's switch in iCloud Drive (or iCloud Drive altogether).

So basically, if you want to check the iCloud status for your app/logging in and logging out events, you subscribe to `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification`. If you want to know when data has changed in iCloud for your app on other devices, you subscribe to `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.didChangeExternallyNotification`.

Most apps likely will want to subscribe to both, although switching iCloud accounts on a device is admittedly not something I have ever had to do other than when I was debugging my iOS app!